# How to make site mobile-friendly using Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and my site have some issues when I'm opening it in mobile device.

My header looks very bad, when I resize the window it looks like this:

[image]

It should be like this in all devices:

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
     <ul class="nav pull-right">

          <li><a href="index.html"><b>Home</b></a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>

          <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-togle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <b>Download</b>
          <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="downloading_link.html">Meepo for iPhone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="not_active">Android coming soon</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>

          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="faq.html"><b>F.A.Q.</b></a></li>
          <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
          <li><a href="support/index.html" id="last_link"><b>Support</b></a>
          </li>  
        </ul>
```

and CSS:

```
   .navbar .nav.pull-right {
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-top:40px;
   margin-right: 0;
   background-image: url('../img/menuBG.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height:57px;
   }
```

I think I need to remove background image here, to make it usable on mobile devices.

Can I make it look better on moble devices (the same as in PC)? I need to write some new css ONLY for mobile phones ? Maybe I shouldn't use responsive css for resizing ?

Comment: To make it responsive, you have to include the `bootstrap-responsive.css` too. The `background-image` has nothing to do with your issue in this case. Full HTML code is appreciated

// Edit: just had to search for the link. Please check this. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: @Sn0opy, I DO use responsive.css but I think I'm making some mistakes in code. My images has static width and when I resize window it stays with same width, so it makes it look like this. My problem is in WRONGLY using responsive css. Can you tell what I could made wrong ? Stupid question, but still I'm stuck.

Comment: Go to http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar - there's an explaination how to use the navbar for responsive designs. It uses a different navbar on mobile devices / lower resolution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is do to overflow.

You need to either set overflow to hidden or none;
There's a few other things you can do to prevent this from happening.

Settings the viewport meta-tag correctly can help, that would look something like this:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='user-scalable=no'>
```

You can also use relational values for your menu items that scale well, such as ems or percentages.  A quick way to convert px values to ems is to divide by the parent element's font-size (usually the body being around 16px)

So your CSS would now look something like this:

```
.navbar .nav.pull-right {
   margin-left: 0.625em;
   margin-top: 2.5em;
   margin-right: 0;
   background-image: url('../img/menuBG.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height:3.5em;
}
```